# Differences in behavior for different openssl versions

Tags: linux, bash, openssl, versioning

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here, but I've got all of my passwords saved in a file as encrypted strings. The command I use to encrypt them is something like:

```
echo "password" | openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -a -nosalt
```

I then use `password` as the encryption key.

Originally (using openssl version 1.0.2g), this resulted in the string

```
7Lz5dLLYCLCv9GjadL1LTQ==
```

which has been saved to the passwords file. However, when I now run the same command using version 1.1.0g, I get the string

```
qq26+CHHB6MuY33GAqeIVw==
```

This means that when I now come to decode my passwords, they do not decode correctly. Is there something that I'm missing here?

> NB: I know that the `nosalt` option is a bad idea, and I don't actually use it. I've just included it here to help clarify my problem.

Comment: The [`openssl enc` man page](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man1/enc.html) does not list a change, like changing the default hash to SHA-512. Maybe the release notes mention something. If all else fails then try `-md md5` and `-md sha1` options. You should probably use `echo -n` explicitly to avoid the new line when testing on different systems. It often leads to different results.

Comment: Yup, the -md md5 has done it. Thanks so much. Pity about it not being in the man doc... had me searching for hours.

Comment: openssl is a mess when different versions cannot even interoperate properly. You will be "searching for hours" because they are poor documented, and hidden in a corner.
Don't waste your youth over it. Those hours are already wasted for nothing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default hash used to generate the encryption key from the password changed between OpenSSL 1.0.2 and OpenSSL 1.1.0.

See this FAQ entry:

https://www.openssl.org/docs/faq.html#USER3

In 1.0.2 the default hash is md5, in 1.1.0 it is sha256. Specify the hash you want to use with the "-md" option.

Comment: Seems like a documentation bug. `man openssl enc` should clearly document it.